# Python Tkinter GUI not responding

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm running pycharm on the mac and noticed that the GUI would not open when it previously has. It bounces in the dock and then says that it is not responding.

So I wrote a very simple program to test the GUI and it still doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
var = 0
one = Label(root, textvariable=var)
one.pack()
while 1 == 1:
    var = random.randint(1, 100)
    time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried reinstalling python but it doesn't help. Also, for my other program,         `textvariable` wasn't able to work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You've told it to sleep in an infinite loop. Why do you find it surprising that the GUI is not responding? It can't respond because it's asleep.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the GUI to run and be responsive, `mainloop` has to execute. But your `mainloop` will never execute, because your `while 1 == 1:` loop will never finish. If you want to do something every second, remove that loop and use `root.after` instead.

---

Your `textvariable` isn't working because `var` is an integer. It needs to be a StringVar.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the fact that textvariable does not display anything. It is just blank.